# How can I assign a value to an array with dynamic nesting?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to do something like this, but dynamically:

```
switch (scope) {
    case 1: array.push("something nice"); break;
    case 2: array[array.length-1].push("something nice"); break;
    case 3: array[array[array.length-1].length-1].push("something nice"); break;
    case 4: ...you get the idea
}
```

That means, if I have an array like this:

[1,2,[5,3,9,[4]]]

and I enter the switch when scope = 3, the result would be:

[1,2,[5,3,9,[4,"something nice"]]]

however, if scope = 2, the result would be:

[1,2,[5,3,9,[4],"something nice"]]

The code I wrote works for this, but I want to make it dynamically (without the switch) when scope can be equal to any number (asumming the array will always have that scope from beforehand, without the need to add new nesting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a recursion and push if `scope` is one.

(Personally if think a zero based scoping would be more natural, in sense of programming.)

```js
function push(array, scope, value) {
    if (scope === 1) return array.push(value);
    push(array[array.length - 1], scope - 1, value);
}

const array = [1, 2, [5, 3, 9, [4]]];

push(array, 3, 'something nice');

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```